# Arranging a Numbers along a Circle

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, geometry, qtquick2

I have a list of numbers, e.g.

```
property var numbers: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]
```

which I want to arrange in a circle, like in a clock.

I tried to use a *QML Clock Example* but I failed to adapt it.
How can I generate that arrangement dynamically using QML tools?

Comment: Seriously, closing for **too broad**, when it has a short and simple answer (that is already provided at the time of closing)? *Off-Topic* for it is missing any approach the OP might have tried would be possible. But **too broad** is really missing the point. The only explanation I have for this, is that almost all *closers* are from  fields unrelated to Qt/QML so they are tempted to answer: "You might do it with some other language", thus resulting in way too many possible answers. But that would be because their answers are *not answers to the question*. Please use your votes responsible!

Comment: @derM If you edit the question in an appropriate way it is not broad, but if we return to the original question then you will see that the author has not tried to solve anything, this leads to the author getting used to asking this type of questions without showing any effort. SO is not a coding service, the author must show what he has tried.

Comment: Then why would we. "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question." and not: "If you can not be helpful be that to the fullest."

Answer (score 2):

You can either calculate their position, using trigonomical functions or such, or you use `Item`s as 'spokes' that you simply rotate, and anchor the `Text`-elements to the top.

This might look like this:

```
Repeater {
    id: rep
    model: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110]

    delegate: Item {
        height: 100
        anchors.bottom: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.left: center.horizontalCenter
        transformOrigin: Item.Bottom
        rotation: 360 / rep.model.length * index
        Text {
            text: modelData
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            rotation: -parent.rotation // If you want to have them upright
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to have the text upright, comment out the last rotation.

Comment: excuse me how can i change my circle to Semicircular?

Comment: You see the `rotation: 360 / rep.model.length * index`. The 360 is the full angle range in degree. 360 is a full circle. Change it to e.g. 180 for only half a circle. Add or subtract a number of degrees, to adjust the starting angle. It might look like this: `rotation: 180 / rep.module.length * index - 90`

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, please don't forget to upvote it. If it answers your question sufficiently also check it as *accepted*. Thank you!