# How to write a for loop in qml?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I am trying to add tick marks for dial on qml. I made the calculations and created the tick marks manually but want them to appear automatically based on the step size of the dial. My idea is to use a for loop but I don't know how to call the javascript in qml. Is the for loop the way to go and how does the code look like? Or do you have a better, more qml-like solution?

```
for i = (0,n):
  gamma = alpha+i*delta
  mix = sin (gamma) * (a+r+l/2)
  miy = cos (gamma) * (a+r+l/2)
  create tick mark i with mix, miy, gamma, l
end for
```

This is the logic that I want to put in the loop.

Comment: Are the tick marks represented visually with some sort of QQuickItem or do you have a canvas on which you are drawing? In the first case, I'd advise to use a Repeater

Comment: Read [JavaScript Expressions in QML Documents](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-expressions.html) to understand how to call JavaScript code in QML.

Comment: QML solutions for similar requirement: [47189087](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47189087/16586783), [50044657](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50044657/16586783)

Answer (score 1):

You should write your for loop inside a function like below:

```
function doing_in_loop() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)  {
      console.log(i)
  }
}
```

or do in on a signal:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
   for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)  {
      console.log(i)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get the following error when I used this.
unexpected token 'for' unexpected token 'var' expected token ','

Comment: Move this code into a function or into a signal handler to resolve the error.